# in powershell, copy-item and test-path are both failing silently.. is it my code, or something else...?

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy, copy-item

I frequently have to copy a single file to multiple destinations, so i'm trying to write a script to make that go faster. it seems to work fine when i'm dealing with local files, but fails without any errors when running on a file that is on a mapped network drive.

at first I was using copy-item, and I couldn't make that work, so i used robocopy. that does the trick, but if the file already exists, i have an if statement using test-path which is supposed to skip to a user input that asks if you want to overwrite.. this is not working. i should say the one that checks the folder exists is working, but the one that checks for the file name always comes back true. for now, i have it just forcing an overwrite with robocopy because most of the time that's what i'll want to do anyway.

here's what i have right now.. "K:" is the mapped network drive i'm copying to, and i'm usually copying files from another mapped network drive "T:". I also should mention i have this set up to run from the context menu in windows (7) explorer, and it passes the file path to the script via %L and $args.

any advice is appreciated. (i apologize in advance, i know it's rather rough.. This is somewhat new to me.)

```
$Folders = @("K:\OKKHM 800" , "K:\OKKHM 1000" , "K:\OKKHM 1002" , "K:\OKKHM 1003" , "K:\OKKHM 1004", "K:\OKKHM 1250") 
$source = $args[0]
$Filename = Split-Path -Path $source -Leaf
$sourcefolder= split-path -path $source -parent
$COUNTER = 0
$successful=0
$CONFIRMATION=0
foreach($Folder in $Folders){ 

    $newpath = $folder + "\" + $filename
            WRITE-HOST $NEWPATH
    if(-not(test-path -path $newpath)) {
        if((test-path -path $folder)) {
                WRITE-HOST 'TEST 2'
            robocopy $sourcefolder $folder $filename -is -it
            $successful=1
        }
        else{
            write-host 'folder does not exist'
        }
    }   
    
    else {
        
        $title    = 'Existing File Will Be Overwritten'
        $question = 'Are you sure you want to proceed?'
        $choices = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]
        $choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&Yes'))
        $choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&No'))
        $decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
    
        if ($decision -eq 0) {
            Write-Host 'confirmed'
            $CONFIRMATION=1
        } 
        else {
            Write-Host 'cancelled'
            $CONFIRMATION=0
        
        }
        IF ($CONFIRMATION -EQ 1) {
            try {
 
                    robocopy $sourcefolder $folder $filename
                $successful=1
                }
            catch { 
                throw "NO GOOD"
            }
        }

    }
    
$COUNTER++
}
if ($successful -eq 1) {
    WRITE-HOST 'SUMMARY: ' $COUNTER ' FILES COPIED SUCCESSFULLY.'
}
Start-Sleep 5
```

Comment: At the moment of runtime, what is `$source = $args[0]` ?

Comment: Are you using a separate account to copy the file(s)?

Comment: $args[0] is the literal path of the program to be copied.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean about a separate account.. could you elaborate?

Comment: Some people (*like myself*), work in an environment that requires us to have a separate "Admin" account to do anything administratively. So we open PowerShell using a separate account, but I will take that as a no:) lol

Comment: Quoting issue. Does it work with folders without spaces?

Comment: Yes! after some testing, i find that it works properly as long as the source path contains no spaces.. the filename can have spaces, but not the folder.

Comment: ok, no.. i mis-interpreted that. it's actually to do with the file name, not the source path. but the file name can have spaces.. so it must be that there are brackets in the file name? my file names look like "VM0780 [10043861 OKKHM].TXT"
yes, that appears to be it..

Comment: aaaand after some quick googling i figured out the solution. i just used test-path with -literalpath instead of just -path, and voila! thanks for pointing me in the right direction iRon!

Comment: new to stackoverflow as well.. should i post my own answer to the question? or leave it as it is?

Comment: Post your answer - then mark it as correct